# How do I use SimpleRepository without the migration approach?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, simplerepository

I am evaluating SubSonic for use in Phase 2 of a large project.  This is an ASP.NET project, with 700 tables in a SQL Server database.

We are planning for our domain model to consist of POCO classes to assist with an offline access requirements we have.  I believe that the SimpleRepository pattern would be among my best options.

Since I have a database already, however, the migration assistance doesn't help me.  Are there T4 templates for SimpleRepository that I just overlooked?  How do I 'turn off' migration?  If I missed something in the Wiki, point me there, otherwise get me started and I'll write up a Wiki entry for y'all when we get there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look at the [linq templates](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_AdvancedTemplates). They're generated from your database just like the ActiveRecord templates but give you POCOs instead.
Alternatively you can just use the simple templates and never run migrations, migrations only happen when you explicitly tell them to (by specifying SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations while creating your repository) so it's not so much that you need to turn them off, just don't turn them on.